# Ag-grid how to update a specific cell style after click

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I use `refreshCells` to update a specific cell style after clicking on it. However, this does not work, and when I set `refreshCells({ force: true })`, the whole column updates new style that I don't want. Any suggestions please?

```
    vm.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: vm.columnDefs,
        rowData: vm.rows,
        angularCompileRows: true,
        defaultColDef: {
            sortable: true,
            resizable: true,
        },
        onCellClicked: onCellClicked,
        onGridReady: function (params) {

        }
    }

    function onCellClicked(params) {
        const focusedCell =  params.api.getFocusedCell();
        focusedCell.column.colDef.cellStyle = { 'background-color': '#b7e4ff' };
        params.api.refreshCells({
            force: true // this updates the whole column, not only the clicked cell
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by setting the specific `rowNodes` and `columns`.

```
    function onCellClicked(params) {
        const focusedCell =  params.api.getFocusedCell();
        const rowNode = params.api.getRowNode(focusedCell.rowIndex);
        const column = focusedCell.column.colDef.field;
        focusedCell.column.colDef.cellStyle = { 'background-color': '#b7e4ff' };
        params.api.refreshCells({
            force: true,
            columns: [column],
            rowNodes: [rowNode]
        });
    }
```

Comment: This gives me the same problem.  Instead of updating the cellStyle as shown, this works ```if (params.node.id === rowNode.id && params.column.colId === column) {
          return { 'background-color': defaultEditedBackground }
        }```